# Travis, how to deploy with ssh?

Tags: continuous-integration, travis-ci, continuous-deployment

I'm using Travis CI pointing to my master branch on a GitHub repository.
Travis is working fine so far for running tests but I still need to manually deploy the code after the code has successfully finished.
I would like to automate this process using Travis again and deploy my _build folder to my server's /var/www/project_folder using ssh.
Is that good? If yes, how can tell Travis to deploy after the tests?

Comment: There's a [deploy](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#The-Build-Lifecycle) build step you should be able to use, assisted by an SSH key encrypted via [travis-encrypt](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encrypting-files) and a little bit of Linux magic.

Comment: Ok thanks but my question is: is this a good way for deploying a website or should I consider doing it differently?

Comment: IMHO, yes, it is a very good way of deploying to any remote servers in general.